# Django collectstatic AWS S3

Tags: django, amazon-aws

Eu tenho uma dúvida referente ao `collectstatic`. Estou usando o Free Tier da Amazon e percebi que ultrapassei o limite de uso do S3 PUT pois fiz vários `collectstatic`. Estava um dia desenvolvendo no próprio ambiente de amazon por preguiça e a cada mudança no JS que eu fazia, como não sabia fazer `collectstatic` de 1 arquivo, fazia geral.

A forma mais eficiente no caso de pequenas edições é fazer `collectstatic -i folder/file.png` (no arquivo ou pasta específica) ou preciso fazer geral? Como não sobrecarregar os envios do S3?

Sei que vacilei fazendo vários `collectstatic` em ambiente de "produção". Mas preciso fazer de todos os arquivos sempre?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O correto é você enviar apenas aquilo que você alterou, não faz sentido enviar 100MB de arquivos para o S3 se você alterou apenas 1 arquivo de 10Kb.

Eu normalmente organizo bem meus diretórios, exemplo:

- static/img/
- static/videos/
- static/videos/homepage

Ao rodar o collecstatic, ignore todos os diretórios que você não alterou, inclusive o 'admin'. Caso o arquivo que você alterou esteja em um diretório com muitos outros arquivos, você pode ignorar extensões também.

Em meu fabfile eu costumo criar um dicionário com a árvore de diretórios do meu static, e nele eu informo qual vai ser ignorado ou não, exemplo:

```
ignore = {
    'app': {
        'img': None
    }
}
```

Você pode criar a lógica e organizar como bem entender, em meu projeto fiz algo mais simples. A ideia é ignorar o diretório pai, ou indicar especificamente os diretórios filhos.

Comment: Cara legal, bem legal. Eu não sei como ignorar arquivos. Eu ja ouvi falar que so de organizar o timezone do settings ja resolveria porque ele iria verificar os horarios de mudanca e so subir o que foi modificado. Porem nao ta rolando comigo. Pra falar a verdade apenas 1 vez funcionou, depois sempre ta subindo todos os arquivos. Voce poderia me dizer onde eu crio esse ignore files? No meu caso eu queria subir apenas o meu `/static/css/main.css` e `/static/js/main.js`. Obrigado!

Comment: Eu uso `fabric`, você pode ver mais informações nesse site http://www.fabfile.org, você roda o comando no terminal que lê o arquivo com a lógica que você definiu, e ele executa os procedimentos. No meu caso eu criei um método  `def collecstatic` que acessa o meu EC2 e roda o collectstatic com a lista de arquivos ignorados que eu mesmo defini.

Comment: É estranho não funcionar naturalmente. Meu s3 está configurado para ara America do Sul, e em um outro projeto que trabalho funciona de boa. Ele identifica o horário da mudança do arquivo e sobe só os que foram modificados. Será que só existe essa maneira mesmo?